# Can I manually apply Grails routing logic to a String containing a URL?

Tags: grails, routes, url-mapping

At runtime, my app will be provided receive a String that *may* be a valid URL that my app serves (per `UrlMappings.groovy`), or it may not. I'd like to determine which is the case.

Is there a way for me to apply Grails routing logic manually to a URL, and see what controller/params (if any) it maps to?

Just to be clear, let's say my `UrlMappings` are:

```
"/path/one" (controller:"api", action:"one")
"/path/two" (controller:"api", action:"two")
"/variable/$segment/1" (controller:"api", action:"var")
```

Now my app receives a string at runtime with the value "/path/fake" -- can I test "/path/fake" against the list of all known routes to determine that it's not a match? (Or alternatively, can I test "/variable/segA/1" and determine that it's associated with the "var" action of my API controller?"

Note: I'm looking for a solution that will work for paths with variables, etc -- and will populate a params array with those variables.

Answer (score 1):

Check whether the mapping is present from the list of mappings available in `UrlMappings` using `grailsApplication` which can be injected easily in artefacts like controller/service.

```
def allMappings = grailsApplication.allClasses
                        .find{it.name == "UrlMappings"}.mappings.urlMappings

assert '/path/one' == allMappings.find{it.toString() == "/path/one"}?.toString()
assert !allMappings.find{it.toString() == "/path/fake"}?.toString()
```

Comment: Thanks @dmahapatro. I updated my question to clarify that I don't just want string-matching: I want to access the Grails routing match logic including variable matches, etc.

Comment: @Bosh Just print `allMappings` from the answer and see what you get. I hope you would see `/variable/(*)/1` in the list.

Comment: Your logic for testing entries `allMappings` against a given string doesn't reproduce what `Grails` does internally: you're just doing string comparison with `==`.  What I want is a way to match and bind parameters just the way that Grails routing does (preferably by relying on Grails internals).